# Jsch shell commands with x11forwarding - reuse channel and run new command

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I need to run ssh command that opens GUI applications.
I was able to get Jsch to run the commands and the GUIs are showing up on the client machine.  My problem is I can't seem to get beyond 20 Jsch channel.  I realize that the server has a setting that controls the number of ssh connection a user can make which here seems to be 20.  What I can't understand is how to reuse an existing connection but run a different command....

I tried to run the commands two different ways:

```
EXAMPLE Command:  

String command = "cd /home/test;xterm ";
String command = "cd /home/test;nedit myfile.txt ";
```

"1 way") each run command creates a new Jsch channel:

```
private void connect (String command) {    
    Channel channel = session.getChannel("shell");
    channel.setXForwarding(true);
    StringBufferInputStream reader = new StringBufferInputStream(command + " \n");
    channel.setInputStream(reader);
    channel.connect();
}
```

[ This code creates a new channel for each new command. works but hitting 20 ssh connection limitation. ]

or

"another way") tried to reuse the channel to run a new command where channel is a global variable:

```
int numruns =0;
private void connect (String command, int channelId)    {
    String cmd = command + " \n";
    if (channel == null) {
        numruns = 0;
        channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setXForwarding(true);
        channel.connect();
        stdIn = channel.getOutputStream();
        stdOut = channel.getInputStream();
    } else {
        channel.connect(channelId);
    }
    ((OutputStream)stdIn).write(cmd.getBytes());
    stdIn.flush();
    numruns++;
}
```

[ "other way" opens the application but it seems to create new ssh connections. so i still have 20 ssh connection limitations.]

So it seems like the server is only allowing maximum of 20 ssh connections.
But why doesn't it work with the "other way"?

So when I close my GUI applications, it doesn't seems to release the ssh connections because it still thinks I have maxed out so I get JschException on channel.connect();

My problem is all the command opens GUI applications so I can't tell when that application is closed to close the channel connection.

I wrote the "other way" method thinking that it will not create a new ssh connection but I should be allowed to use the existing connection but send a new command.  Obviously it doesn't work that way.

How can I accomplish using one ssh connection to run different command when connect(command) is called?  Is that possible with Jsch?

Comment: If you want to just execute a single command in each channel, use an exec channel, not a shell channel. (I don't know if this helps for your problem, though.)

Comment: Also, why are you calling `connect()` again on your "second" way?

Answer (score 0):

Not Solved!  The following works to a point.  It hides the fact that any "xterm" no longer has display information once Jsch channel connection closes.

=====================================

To keep the GUI from disappearing when the channel was disconnected, needed to kick off the command with "nohup" preceding the command or "xterm -hold -e"

So...

EXAMPLE Command:

```
String command = "cd /home/test;xterm";
String command = "cd /home/test;nohup nedit myfile.txt";  // this will only keep the GUI opened
String command = "cd /home/test;xterm -hold -e gedit myfile.txt";  // this one keeps the xterm window that kick off the program opened
```

So after making changes to the command, Thread.sleep(1000) was added so give application time to come up before disconnecting the channel.

This seems to work!

```
private void connect (String command) {    
    Channel channel = session.getChannel("shell");
    channel.setXForwarding(true);
    StringBufferInputStream reader = new StringBufferInputStream(command + " \n");
    // or use
    // ByteArrayInputStream reader = new ByteArrayInputStream((command + " \n").getBytes());
    channel.setInputStream(reader);
    channel.setOuputStream(System.out);
    channel.connect();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // give GUI time to come up
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // print message
    }
    channel.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Apparently once channel is disconnected, I lose the display information.  So if I opened "xterm" window using Jsch then on the X11'd xterm window, I try to open another GUI related command such as "gedit" or "nedit" it opens at the GUI intermittently saying "Display not found".  It seems that although the session is alive the display information got lost when the channel was disconnected.