# Run program in remote computer over ssh via Java (JSch)

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I am writing a block of Java code that allows me to connect to a remote computer and execute a program on it. So far I am able to connect to the program and run it. I can see the program's output on my console. However, the program stops executing and my java code exists with exit code = 0. Here is my connect method. I call it in my main with the correct arguments.

```
    public void listFolderStructure(String username,
                                       String host, int port, String command) throws Exception {

    Session session = null;
    ChannelExec channel = null;

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
        jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();

        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");


        channel.setXForwarding(true);
        channel.setCommand(command);
        ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);
        channel.connect();

        while (channel.isConnected()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        String responseString = new String(responseStream.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(responseString);
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
        if (channel != null) {
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is part the output of the program on my console. Note: Connecting to the remote via ssh and running the program from a terminal gives the same output but the program's gui window displays on my computer and it runs as per usual

```
2021-04-03 20:36:42 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: 
"/home/usr/adtf3.7/bin/adtf_kernel.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1887)]
2021-04-03 20:36:42 [INFO]:     Registered class "kernel.service.adtf.cid". ( 14 ) 
[runtime.cpp(2213)]
2021-04-03 20:36:42 [INFO]: Try to load 
"/home/usr/adtf3.7/bin/adtf_playback.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1784)]
2021-04-03 20:36:42 [INFO]: Loaded plugin: 
"/home/usr/adtf3.7/bin/adtf_playback.adtfplugin" [runtime.cpp(1887)]
2021-04-03 20:36:42 [INFO]:     Registered class "playback.service.adtf.cid". ( 15 ) [

 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there a way to connect to the remote via Jsch and have the program's ui display as it normally would without it exiting? (code 0)
Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Thank you @Martin Prikryl; one of his suggestions helped out and I can now run the program on the remote. The only issue I'm facing now is getting the UI to display on my machine instead of the remote machine

Method that can run programs on the remote:

```
    public void run_command(String command) throws JSchException {
    String username = this.user;
    String host = this.host;
    int port = this.port;

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/id_rsa");

    this.sshSession = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
    this.sshSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
    this.sshSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    this.sshSession.connect();


    this.sshChannel = this.sshSession.openChannel("shell");
    this.sshChannel.setXForwarding(true);

    ByteArrayInputStream reader = new ByteArrayInputStream(("export DISPLAY=:0; "+command + " \n").getBytes());
    this.sshChannel.setInputStream(reader);
    this.sshChannel.setOutputStream(System.out);
    this.sshChannel.connect();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // give GUI time to come up
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // print message
    }
    this.sshChannel.disconnect();
}
```

alternatively this can be used to connect to a remote without Jsch. Extending to command however; i.e: ..this.host;gedit makes the terminal instantly dissapear.

```
public void open_remote_terminal() {
    try {
        String command ="gnome-terminal -x ssh -x "+this.user+"@"+this.host;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what ssh command you use to connect to this server and run the program. Include any relevant entries from your .ssh/config file.

Comment: IIRC, there is an environment variable in the shell that identifies the local X server, and needs to be sent from the local shell to remote shell (or maybe just set on the remote shell) so that any commands that you run there will send their output back here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44826264/850848 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11526478/850848

Comment: @Kenster Via the Terminal I connect normally via ssh -X user@host. The Method in the question is the one I use to connect via my Java Code. The only relevant info in my .ssh config is my pub key which is pushed to the server. I can connect to the server so I presume the SSH connection isn't the issue but the way Jsch handles X forwarding